Amcharts5 - Change bullet radius after chart is loaded
I want to change bullet radius value after chart is loaded. The meaning is to let the user choose the radius by selecting value from dropdown
series.bullets.push(function(root) {
   return am5.Bullet.new(root, {
         sprite: am5.Circle.new(root, {
          radius: 2, // change this AFTER init with my own button
          fill: series.get("fill")
        })
    });
});


I succeeded updating the bullet but nothing changed in UI:
const series = this.chart.series.getIndex(0);
series.bulletsContainer.children.each((bullet) => {
bullet.radius = 10;
});

This is the complete working answer:
const series = this.chart.series.getIndex(0); // take the first series as an example
series.bulletsContainer.children.each((bullet) => {
   bullet.set('radius', 10);
});

